# Is bruxism (teeth grinding) linked to parasitic infection?

Tags: medical-science, dentistry, epidemiology

There seems to be the common conception that [bruxism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruxism) (teeth grinding and jaw clenching) is a symptom of parasitic infections.

For example, [this article by a dentist](https://patch.com/pennsylvania/lowerprovidence/bp--three-common-teeth-grinding-causes-604c71bd):

> Sometimes teeth grinding is caused by worms like intestinal parasites and pin worms.

> This happens more often in countries where there isn't a lot of good drinking water but it can also happen elsewhere. In fact, some alternative health practitioners believe that parasites are far more prevalent than is commonly believed, and this can cause a variety of symptoms, aside from teeth grinding.

However the studies I found seem to be of dubious quality. For example:
[*The Correlation between Intestinal Parasitic Infections and Bruxism among 3-6 Year-Old Children in Isfahan*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3177368/)

Is there any clinical link?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: that's the same study as the one linked to by the OP. It's dubious for example because their claimed p-value is clearly wrong. 11/50 vs 8/50 is not a statistically significan deviation.